# Zagreb: How/where to get tickets for a football game?

Tags: croatia, sports-events, football, zagreb

I am in Zagreb next month. Does anyone know where it would be possible to get a ticket for the football games on? (From a tout is an option I'd consider).  A website, tour office or similar?

Alternatively, will there be any fan parks with large screens showing the game?

Comment: welcome to the site.  If you have a look at our [faq], we try to ask questions that may be useful to future visitors as well.  This means that a question about a single football game on a specific date is far too localised to be of use to anyone else after that date.  I'm going to revise your question to make it more generic, please let me know if the new format is ok.

Comment: related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10737/is-it-safe-to-attend-a-soccer-game-between-croatia-and-serbia-as-a-tourist/10741#10741

Comment: Generally agree with you @MarkMayo, However, tickets for football games are always sold at the usual places (internet, black market, etc.) and places with large screens tend also to be the same places.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException yes, which will happily make the answer continuously useful, I just made the question more generic.  It's why it was garnering too many close votes (it was being flagged as too localised).

Comment: Which football?